# PostgreSQL For OpenERP service is not being started

Tags: python, postgresql

I have installed OpenERP on my windows8 machine, it was working fine for few days, but after then i am getting below error when i start OpenERP, after looking into error i came to know that, error is due to PostgreSQL For OpenERP service, as its not being started. I try to start that service but i am getting this error **"Error 1053: The Service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."** Please help me. Please let me know if i am doing something wrong.

Thanks to all in advance.

Please check below error

**Internal Server Error**

{"message": "OpenERP Server Error", "code": 200, "data": {"debug": "Server Traceback (most recent call last):\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py\", line 89, in send\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py\", line 292, in dispatch_rpc\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py\", line 122, in dispatch\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py\", line 359, in exp_list\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py\", line 484, in cursor\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py\", line 182, in **init**\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py\", line 377, in _locked\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py\", line 440, in borrow\n File \"psycopg2\_*init*_.pyc\", line 178, in connect\nOperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)\n\tIs the server running on host \"localhost\" (::1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\ncould not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)\n\tIs the server running on host \"localhost\" (127.0.0.1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\n\n\nClient Traceback (most recent call last):\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py\", line 285, in dispatch\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py\", line 573, in index\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py\", line 98, in db_monodb_redirect\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py\", line 109, in db_redirect\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py\", line 90, in db_list\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py\", line 30, in proxy_method\n File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py\", line 103, in send\nFault: \n", "fault_code": "could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)\n\tIs the server running on host \"localhost\" (::1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\ncould not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)\n\tIs the server running on host \"localhost\" (127.0.0.1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\n", "type": "server_exception"}}

Comment: Is PostgreSQL running on the machine? I assume it has been installed as a service. Please see if you can start PostgreSQL.

Comment: i don't have PostgreSQL installed separately, it came up as service with OpenERP. In Service list, its name is "PostgreSQL_For_OpenERP - PostgreSQL Server 9.2"

Comment: OK. Is it running? If not, can you start it from services?

Comment: I try to start that service but i am getting this error "Error 1053: The Service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion." Please help me.

Comment: hmm..remote support getting trickier. Try starting the database from command line and see what error you are getting. You may need to set PATH and PGDATA variables and use pg_ctl start command.http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pg-ctl.html